# why is my integer increasing by 2 instead of 1? java

Tags: java, while-loop, int, increment

I have implemented code that's like a simple clock, it should just increase by 1 every time in my class. So far this is what I have in the main program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BoundedCounter counter = new BoundedCounter(60);
    System.out.println("Value at start: " + counter);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        counter.next();
        System.out.println("Value: " + counter);
        i++;
    }
}
```

and here is the class "BoundedCounter" :

```
class BoundedCounter {

    private int value;
    private int upperBound;

    public BoundedCounter(int upperBound) {
        this.upperBound = upperBound;
        this.value = 0;  
    }

    public void next () {
        if (value++ > upperBound) { 
            value = 0;
        } else {
            value++;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "" + value;
    }
}
```

The output for this code is:

```
Value at start: 0
Value: 2
Value: 4
Value: 6
Value: 8
Value: 10
Value: 12
Value: 14
Value: 16
Value: 18
Value: 20
```

I don't understand why it's increasing by 2, when in the class the while statement has `value++`; which means it should increase by 1.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're calling `value++` twice in `next()`.

Comment: `if(value++){} else{value++}` you do it twice

Comment: Because you are doing `++` two times: once in `if (value++ ...` and once a few lines later in the `else` block.

Comment: Even in the condition of the `if` you are using `value++` which will increment the value even if the condition isnt met after that line executes, which is why it is increments by 2

Answer (score 11):

Your `if` executes `value++` and then (assuming the `else` is entered) you do it again. Change

```
if (value++ > upperBound) { 
    value = 0;
} else {
    value++;
}
```

To something like

```
if (value + 1 > upperBound) { 
    value = 0;
} else {
    value++;
}
```

**or**

```
if (value < upperBound) {
    value++;
} else {
    value = 0;
}
```

Comment: (Or remove the else).

Comment: @AndyTurner depends if he wants to increment either way or only in the second case

Comment: (Or `if (value >= upperBound)`)

Comment: `if (value >= upperBound)` is a safer way to write it, as it avoids integer overflow problems when `upperBound == Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @Rafalon certainly why not?

Comment: @AndyTurner nothing, noticed my mistake ^^